# How to get client local timezone not server timezone by using PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

How can we detect user's local time?
For example,

> My server is located in USA and date time is 27-Mar-2014 01:10:10. (GMT0)
>   I use my PC access to my website from Cambodia and date time is 27-Mar-2014 08:10:10. (GMT+7).

How can I get my PC datetime when I access to my website at USA?

Please help!

Comment: You cannot. You could provide a way for the user to specify his/her local time zone, and store it in the user profile, but AFAIK there is no way you can determine a client's time zone from the browser alone.

Comment: On another note, any time in the US is certainly not GMT, but has a negative offset. If your server actually reports it's local time as GMT (+/-0), then it's not configured properly.

Comment: Hi! In fact, before I insert datetime to database, I convert it to UTC or GMT0.

Comment: Hi! Can we detect client's IP Address then detect country?

Comment: Perhaps, this is what you are looking for.[The link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me

```
  echo <<<EOE
   <script type="text/javascript">
     if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
       document.cookie = "tzo="+ (- new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
   </script>
EOE;
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['tzo'])) {
    echo <<<EOE
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (navigator.cookieEnabled) document.reload();
        else alert("Cookies must be enabled!");
      </script>
EOE;
    die();
  }
  $ts = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
  $ts->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($_COOKIE['tzo'].' minutes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send it to the server using javascript(which runs on the client and can access the system time)