# datetime according to country in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am working on php site i have to show date and time after user login in header section. The problem is that I have to set a default timezone in datetimezone() function php. I have server of USA and I want if anyone is accessing this site in UK then it should show his/her datetime according to his location, I have used the way of getting IP address of client, but it did not work.

Comment: use this get local time var now = new Date();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client

Comment: Maybe this previous post is exactly what you need: [get user timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone)