# How to localize a date in Liquid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, liquid

In my Rails 5 app I am using [Liquid](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/) to let my users generate content.

Based on my users input, I init my template with something like this:

```
string   = "Order {{ order.id }} was created {{ order.date | date: '%A %d/%m-%Y' }}"
template = Liquid::Template.parse(string)
result   = template.render({'order' => {'id' => '123', 'date' => order.date}})
```

This would print something a la:

```
'Order 123 was created Sunday 14/01-2018'
```

But how do I build Liquid date localization into my Rails app?

It does not seem to be supported in [the documentation](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/). However [Shopify themselves seems to have build localization into their Liquid implementation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/internationalizing/locale-files#date-localization).

I suppose I would need to pass my template a locale (`en`, `fr`, etc.) and a locale file. My Rails locale file looks like this:

```
en:
  datetime: &datetime
    month_names:
      [~, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
    day_names:
      [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]
    abbr_day_names:
      [~, Sun, Mon, Thue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat]
    formats:
       default: "%d/%m/%Y"
       long: "%A %d/%m-%Y"
```

And I call it with:

```
l(order.date, :format => :long, :locale => 'en')
```

I would love to have access to a similar date localization inside my Liquid template.

Comment: You might be able to deliberately call `I18n.localize` ? http://www.stackednotion.com/blog/2015/01/03/formatting-dates-and-times-in-rails-with-i18n-localize/ seems relevant - it shows how to deliberately pass in a locale and use a customised date format (but note I've spent like maybe 5 whole seconds thinking about this...)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/biow0lf/1486342 ?

Comment: Thanks @Ben I've used this approach to register a filter that does `l(order.date, :format => :long, :locale => 'en')`. I'm gonna write it in as an answer if no one else comes up with a better solution. But it's not a perfect one, because it limits me to a set of predefined `formats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the link proveded by @Ben, and wrote up this solution:

```
# config/initializers/liquid_filters.rb
module I18nFilters
  def l(date, format)
    I18n.l(date, :format => format.to_sym)
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(I18nFilters)
```

Now, when invoking that new method:

```
{{ order.date | l: 'long' }}
```

it will print out:

```
'Sunday 14/01-2018'
```

with `Sunday` being whatever is in `day_names` withing the locale file.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your date object with order.date

```
result   = template.render({'order' => {'id' => '123', 'date' => order.date}})
```

Can you pass a localized date or localized datetime? Then when it gets rendered it should be correct.

Otherwise, you could add the date to a span with class name you can target (for fallback) and "fix" it on the client side with a combination of pure Javascript and a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161134/793330
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```

Comment: Hi @engineerDave modifying with js is a hack that I want to avoid. But the first suggestion seems more like a question to me. I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: sorry words are hard. :) When you pass order.date to the liquid template, I would assume you know the locale of the person you're displaying the data for, if not you can do this within rails, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html. This will allow you to pass the correctly localized date to the template.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing only a reference to `t` method.

Instead of

```
string   = "Order {{ order.id }} was created {{ order.date | date: '%A %d/%m-%Y' }}"
```

Try with

```
string   = "Order {{ order.id }} was created {{ order.date | t: date: '%A %d/%m-%Y' }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the JavaScript Intl API.

Add this filter to `.eleventy.js`:

```
  eleventyConfig.addFilter("displayDate", function(date, locale) {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { dateStyle: "long" }).format(date);
  });
```

Now you can show localized dates by using this in, for example, your Liquid template:

```
{{ date | displayDate: locale }}
```

Here, `date` contains the date and `locale` contains the locale.