# All the timings and reports should be in user based timezone.Not limited to any particular timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, redux, frontend

I have been trying to convert my standard PST *timestamps* (All over my app including some reports) into whatever the timezone the system is logged into. Simply I can say displaying all the timings and reports should be in user based timezone. What would be the best optimized way to implement it using JS.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like this question already has an answer here:

[How to get the exact local time of client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client)

check out the second solution