# How to reject non UTC/GMT dates from client in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core

I want to force clients (web, android, ios) to send the API only time in UTC/GMT.

This means that they get user's local time (using any method), convert it to UTC/GMT, and then send it to the API.

And I want to reject any datetime parameter that is not in UTC/GMT.

In JavaScript, I can get UTC this way:

`new Date().toUTCString()` which gives this result:

'Mon, 15 Nov 2021 04:26:38 GMT'

And I send this string to the API:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Parse(string clientDateTime)
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse(clientDateTime);
    return new 
    {
        ParsedDate = date,
        Kind = date.Kind.ToString()
    };
}
```

However, I see that .NET parses this date time as `Local` and not as `Utc`. This is in spite of the string containing GMT.

How can I check the incoming datetime and make sure it's UTC/GMT?

Comment: you can use DateTime.Parse(clientDateTime).ToUniversalTime() , for converting local to utc.

Comment: No, that should not be necessary. That might change the date time based on offsets and server's local time. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct, if this DateTime is nonlocal then you should use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Manish, then whole point of this method is to not get stuck in the concept of `TimeZone`. Each user has his own time zone, and we do the conversion on the client-side. This way, we don't have to deal with user's time-zone on the server.

Comment: Take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript

Comment: yaa I understood your issue, but this is the default behaviour of DateTime.Parse. it will convert using DateTimeKind.Local unless a specific timezone is specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your problem by using a conventional format for datetime serialization. A common choice for this problem is using the ISO 8601 datetime format.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you can find an in depth explanation of this format, but as an example this is a datetime in the ISO 8601 format: `2021-11-15T06:40:48.204Z` (the final `Z` indicates that the datetime represented by this string is `UTC`)

The main advantage in fixing a format for date and times is that **you will know in advance the format** and you will be in a much better position to parse the datetime strings on the server.

Using the ISO 8601 format is a good choice, because it is a well known format and it is the standard de facto for the datetime serialization: this basically means that anyone writing a client for your application will be able to comply with the required format. **Of course, you are required to clearly document this convention so that your clients (or your fellow developers) will be aware of it.**

Another tip is using the `DateTimeOffset` struct instead of `DateTime`. `DateTimeOffset` is basically used to represent a specific point in time and that's exactly what you want: your clients will send you ISO 8601 strings representing a point in time and you want to know that point in time in your application.

Your clients will be able to use any time zone to express the point in time they want to send to your application. Doing this using an UTC datetime or any other time zone is just an implementation detail. Once you have parsed the datetime string to a `DateTimeOffset` instance, if you really want to, you can check whether it is an UTC time by checking the [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=net-5.0) property: it will be a zero `TimeSpan` value if the `DateTimeOffset` instance represents an UTC date and time.

In order to manipulate date in a Javascript client application I strongly suggest to use the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library. Check [this docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) to see how to get an ISO 8601 string with Moment.js

You can use [this helper method](https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/deltatre.utils/blob/07514f2ca3699fa47d1f03f57a2cd7719fcef794/src/Deltatre.Utils/Parsers/DateParsers.cs#L68) to parse an ISO 8601 string to a `DateTimeOffset` instance. This implementation allows the client to send you a broad range of ISO 8601 compliant string formats, if you want you can be stricter by reducing the number of allowed formats (see the [`Iso8601Formats`](https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/deltatre.utils/blob/07514f2ca3699fa47d1f03f57a2cd7719fcef794/src/Deltatre.Utils/Parsers/DateParsers.cs#L12) static field in the code).

To summarize:

- ask your clients to only send you datetime strings in a format compliant with the ISO8601 specification. **Clearly document this choice**
- for a Javascript client use a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to manipulate date and times. This will be much simpler than using plain old javascript `Date` objects.
- if you are manipulating date time strings representing a specific point in time, use the `DateTimeOffset` struct instead of the `DateTime` struct. `DateTimeOffset` represents a specific point in time expressed in a certain time zone. The `Offset` property represents the difference between the point in time represented by the `DateTimeOffset` instance and UTC: its value will be a zero `TimeSpan` if the `DateTimeOffset` instance represents an UTC datetime. Notice that the point in time will always be the same regardless the time zone it is referring to, so using UTC doesn't make any real difference (it's just an implementation detail at this point).
- use code like [this one](https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/deltatre.utils/blob/07514f2ca3699fa47d1f03f57a2cd7719fcef794/src/Deltatre.Utils/Parsers/DateParsers.cs#L68) to parse a `DateTimeOffset` instance from a string. This code tries as many ISO 8601 compliant formats as possible (this is done in order to accept as many valid formats as possible). If you want, you can decide to be stricter: to do that, just reduce the number of formats in the [`Iso8601Formats`](https://github.com/deltatre-webplu/deltatre.utils/blob/07514f2ca3699fa47d1f03f57a2cd7719fcef794/src/Deltatre.Utils/Parsers/DateParsers.cs#L12) array.

A final note on your code. The behaviour you are observing from `DateTime.Parse` is exactly the expected one. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_) for `DateTime.Parse`:

> Converts the string representation of a date and time to its DateTime
> equivalent by using the conventions of the current thread culture.

`DateTime.Parse` is basically designed to use the locale settings of the machine running the code.

If you want to learn more on the difference between `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`  you can check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset).