# Retrieve local time with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the local time in my country Indonesia?

```
var date = new Date();
var local = date.getLocal();
```

I know the above code doesn't work, how do I retrieve it?  I want to take (WIB) western Indonesian time / Waktu Indonesia Barat.

Please help me, all answers are like precious gold.

Comment: Did you try that `date.toLocaleTimeString()`

Comment: Down vote because the question does not show any research effort.  The information is easily available in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the exact local time of client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a Timezone using the [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

```js
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' });
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a third party API to show time from a specific country. You can use API from `worldtimeapi.org/`. Make an ajax call, get the time of your desired location. You can use plain javascript or use any ajax library to do that. Here I'm doing it in plain javascript

```
function getTime(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url);
        req.onload = () =>
            req.status === 200
                ? resolve(req.response)
                : reject(Error(req.statusText));
        req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
        req.send();
    });
}
```

Now Use this function to make the ajax call

```
let url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Pacific/Auckland";

getTime(url)
    .then((response) => {
        let dateObj = JSON.parse(response);
        let dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
        console.log(dateObj);
        console.log(dateTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```